# Extracting Data from SQL Server Using VBA-Excel with Dates Filter - Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I used VBA to extract data from SQL-Server and was able to extract data using text filters but when I started filtering by date, it didn't work anymore. I think my mistake was the formatting of date. I tried using all the samples on this site but I'm beginning to be hopeless. It would be great if you guys can assist me with this hurdle. Thanks a million.

Here's the code: (*Please take note that I am skipping the connection and close codes to focus only on the problematic source code*).

What I want to achieve here in this code is to extract all the records (*using SQL query in a VBA environment*) based on date criteria which is greater than or equal to January 1, 2018.

```
        query = "SELECT (Worktype), count(*)" & _
        "FROM dbo.InteractionSummary WHERE [Worktype] IN ('" & MAC & "')" & _
        "GROUP BY [Worktype]"
```

With this query, I had no issue. It has generated the figures perfectly. What these codes do is to count all the records from "Worktype" column that has "MAC" value.

My issue is when I add the below date criteria.

```
        Dim dTheDate As Date
        dTheDate = #1/1/2018#


        query = "SELECT (Worktype), count(*)" & _
        "FROM dbo.InteractionSummary WHERE [Worktype] IN ('" & IMAC & "')" & _
        "GROUP BY [Worktype] AND [StartDateTimeUTC] > " & dTheDate & " "
```

StartDateTimeUTC is a DateTime2 column (datetime2(3),notnull). I'm trying to extract only based on the dTheDate. I tried every format but it's not letting the code through.

Thanks,
Skywalker

Comment: The filter goes in a `WHERE`, not a `GROUP BY`. `WHERE [Worktype] in () AND [StartDateTimeUTC] > ` followed by `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks, Ken White I moved the filter in the WHERE Clause but it was still having an error. Is there something wrong with my date declaration or the way I place the double quotes, hashtags and ampersands? Your suggestion works perfectly in SQL server environment. Its the VBA syntax rules that give me a bit of a problem                             
 .query = "SELECT (Worktype), count(*)" & _
   "FROM dbo.InteractionSummary WHERE [Worktype] IN ('" & IMAC & "') AND [StartDateTimeUTC] > " & dTheDate & "" & _
   "GROUP BY [Worktype]"